# How to get catalog in stock on frontend?

Tags: magento2, catalog, products, stock, inventory

I have done everything everyone subscribes everywhere
From reindex, in stock, manage all, quantity, databases check, double check

But products just don't appear on front end because it says out of stock when I go to the product url:
https://takoda.online/backup/en/catalog/product/view/id/24

While everything seem to be in stock from admin to database.

This happened since I have transferred from a different server, have import my backup.

This issue stay existing.
Already have add Views in database.

Thanks for the golden tip!
Alain

[image: products][image: Product settings][image: catalog inventory][image: catalog inventory 2]